# Enabling Scheduler for spring cloud data flow server in pcf

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, pcf

We are using PCF to run our applications, To build data pipelines we thought of leveraging the Spring cloud data flow server, which is given as service inside PCF.

We created a DataFlow server by giving SQL server and maven repo details, and for the scheduler, we didn't provide any extra parameters while creating service, so by default, it is disabled.
Got some info from here, how to enable scheduler: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_enabling_scheduling

So I tried updating the existing Data Flow service with the below command:

```
cf updat-service my-service -c '{"spring.cloud.dataflow.features.schedules-enabled":true}'
```

the Data Flow server is restarted, but still the scheduler is not enabled to schedule the jobs.
When I check with this endpoint `GET /about` from the Data Flow server, I am still getting

```
"schedulesEnabled": false
```

in response body.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the SCDF service isn't updated with the schedules enabled property even after you update  service (as it is expected to have it enabled).

Irrespective of that you can try setting the following as environment property for SCDF service instance as well:

```
    SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_SCHEDULES_ENABLED: true
```

Once the schedule is enabled, you need to make sure that you have the following properties set correctly as well:

```
SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_TASK_SERVICES: <all-the-services-for-tasks-along-with-the-scheduler-service-instance>
SPRING_CLOUD_SCHEDULER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_SCHEDULER_URL: <scheduler-url>
```